# Providing links and markers [label] in each bar in a bar chart

Tags: charts, dojo

I have recently started working on dojo. I am facing problems in the following cases.

1. How can i provide a unique link (href) in each bar in the bar chart? When a user clicks on a bar or label, he should be taken to a related jsp/html page.Basically, i am looking for a clickable bar or tooltip.

This code didn't works, because it will be rendered as special characters.

```
 chart2.addAxis("y", {
        vertical: true, 
        fixLower: "none", 
        fixUpper: "none", 
        natural: true,
        majorTick: { length: 3 },
           labels: [{value: 1, text: <a href="url">Link text</a> }, ...]
    });



<div id="chart2" style="height: 100px;">
<div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; ...">
<div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; ... ">Link&nbsp;text</div> //label
</div>
...
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do what you ask yet with `dojox.charting`.

FWIW, there's a pretty good example of what you can do with `dojox.charting` at [SitePen.](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2009/04/01/stocker-advanced-dojo-made-easy/)